# Tomcat, site can’t be reached

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I am using Amazon EC2, on my VM installed Tomcat 8.5.8. Everything was ok, but recently i realized that my webapp not working. I didn't change anything, but everytime i try to open it - i get 'This site can’t be reached' error. 
I have custom Security Groups rules for the HTTP traffic (port 80) and also HTTPS traffic (port 443), both on TCP. As i said, everything was ok, but now it's not working :(

here my logs: `https://pastebin.com/hkDZ5HtM`
my website address: `http://antilamer.tk/`

Comment: Did you restart EC2 lately? Do you have any Elastic IP associated with EC2?

Comment: @kosa, yes, i restarted EC2, but it was working after it, i checked. And yes, i have the elastic ip.

Comment: If you have ElasticIP, restart doesn't matter. Next thing security groups, if you have any limitations that only certain IP's can access website, make sure your computer is added there (might have changed from last access), if this also NOT the cause. Last one is see requests are reaching tomcat or not by checking catalina logs.

Comment: @kosa, security groups is ok, i've checked it. But still, i don't have any logs that my requests reaching tomcat

Comment: Ok, if request not reaching tomcat, then problem will be either in DNS or Security groups, I can't think of anything else. Based on the description, it seems you didn't change anything from last working, which leaves to lean more towards IP issue. If you are using R53 make sure  IP configurations are matching with EC2, that's all I can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in Tomcat, i've reinstalled it and now it works.